# Why is my custom sort not working with Material-UI Data Grid component?

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, sorting, material-ui

I have implemented Material-UI's Data Grid Component, taking data in from a JSON array brought back from my API, and have had to implement a RenderCell function to account for text overflow and renders a button to take Users to a separate page. I have also implemented their ValueGetter for extraction to Excel documents and further functionality that will convert values to an empty string should they be undefined or null and have thus implemented a custom sortComparator function as specified in their docs.

However, no matter what implementation I use for the sortComparator, if there are empty cells, they are placed near the top during the ascending sort, but correctly during the descending sort, but if all cells are filled, the sort works as intended.

I want my Data Grid to place all empty cells at the bottom during the sort, for both ascending and descending.

Custom Sort Attempt:

```
    const customSort = (a: GridCellValue, b: GridCellValue) =>
    {
        if(a === '') {
           return 0;
        }
        else {
            return b > a ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> 1. If compareFunction(a, b) returns a value > than 0, sort b before a.
> 2. If compareFunction(a, b) returns a value ≤ 0, leave a and b in the same order.

So, note you shouldn't return 0 if you want the empty cell at the bottom.

You should also use two different customSort functions for ascending and descending order.

```
const customSortAsc = (a,b) => {
  if(a === '') return 1;
  if(b === '') return -1;
  if(a > b) return 1
  if(a < b) return -1;
  if(a === b) return 0;
}

const customSortDesc = (a,b) => {
  if(a === '') return 1;  // Not needed line, here for clarification
  if(b === '') return -1; // Not needed line, here for clarification
  if(a > b) return -1
  if(a < b) return 1;
  if(a === b) return 0;
}

 const initialArray = ['','ddd','aaa','','ccc','bbb',''];

 const sortedArrayAsc = [...initialArray].sort(customSortAsc);
 // sortedArrayAsc = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','','','']

 const sortedArrayDesc = [...initialArray].sort(customSortDesc);
 // sortedArrayDesc = ['ddd','ccc','bbb','aaa','','','']
```